# path may not be null or empty string. path='null'

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to build my react native project build on android studio to run it on emulator. But I am getting an error on android studio saying:

> path may not be null or empty string. path='null'
> This error is from settings.gradle file
> I am attaching the code as follows:

rootProject.name = 'BestRonaldoWallpapers'

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle");
useExpoModules()

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':app'

## includeBuild(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native-gradle-plugin/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile())

It seems the error is in this line. What should I pass in place of null?

I donot know what should be there instead of null?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did anyone find a reason and solution for this issue?